# Visual para zoom in/out usando Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Eu estou usando a API v3 do Google Maps mas um dos efeitos que eu vejo na página do Google eu não estou conseguindo reproduzir.

Esse efeito é a ajuda Visual para zoom in/out, quando você da um zoom na página do Google Maps aparece 4 cantos vermelhos animados (fechando ou abrindo dependendo se o zoom é in ou out) mas pela API esse efeito não aparece.

Como torná-lo disponível?

Answer (score 1):

Se esse efeito não está disponibilizado na API, e você tem certeza que checou até nas versões mais recentes para ver se é alguma funcionalidade nova, vou explicar um modo de fazer isso.

1. **Adicione um evento que é acionado quando há zoomIn e zoomOut**
2. **Detecte a posição atual do mouse na tela**
3. **Exiba um gif animado, que teria exatamente a mesma funcionalidade que o Google oferece, já com a diferença de imagens para zoomIn e zoomOut**

Pode haver outros meios de fazer isso, mas a forma como estou falando, caso não seja disponibilizado via API, certamente vai funcionar.